# Envolver botón en caja de texto

Tags: python, django, css, bootstrap, django-forms

Estoy  tratando  de  poner  un botón  dentro de una  caja de  texto de  mi  formulario pero NO me  funciona. intento hacer algo así como la  imagen  de abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste es mi código actual.

```html
<div class="row">                            
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> 
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class = "input-group">
        <label for="alumno" class="hidden-xs col-sm-2">Alumno:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          {{form.alumno}}
          {{form.persona_display}}
          {{form.persona_display.error}} 
        </div>
        <span class = "input-group-btn">
          <button class = "btn btn-default" type = "button">
            + Alumno
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div> <!-- class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" -->                           
</div> <!--<div class="row"> -->
```

Y éste es mi resultado, ojo solo mostré el código del  Alumno. Todo esto es  con el  fin de que si no existe un  alumno, no tenga  que  salirme  de  esta  pantalla  para dar de alta  un nuevo alumno, simplemente al  darle  clic  al  botón **+ Alumno** me muestre la  pantalla de Alumnos capturar el  nuevo alumno y continuar  con la  captura de  Atención

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Logre adjuntar el  botón con el `input` pero  tuve  que  quitar el `Label` del  alumno y  la clase `class="col-sm-10"`.

Pero  son  necesarias  saben  por que  al  agregar estas  dos lineas de código  se  descuadra..

Este es mi código actual con el que se alinea, pero deseo agregar el `Label` del  alumno  y  la  clase `class="col-sm-10"`

Tienen idea  por que  se descuadra con estas  dos  lineas..?

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        {{form.persona_display}} {{form.persona_display.error}}
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-add"          type="button"><span class="glyphicon                     glyphicon-plus"></span>Alumno</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Creo que estás haciendo varias preguntas, Una sería como obtener correctamente el botón alineado e incrustado conjuntamente con el *input* y para ello échale un ojo a [esto](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/#button-addons), y la segunda sería como obtener las opciones ya existentes en la base de datos para no tener que actualizar la página, quizá [esto](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) te valga.

Comment: Tony, coloca la salida esperada en HTML, así será más fácil ver qué tienes que agregar en tu plantilla y qué tienes que que agregar a tu _widget_.

Comment: Hola kikocorreoso Solo me  interesa  alinera el boton  Las  opciones ya  existentes en la base de datos  ya  me  funciona  correctamente. es  solo alinera el boton,  pero en el  ejemplo que se suguieres  usan  un  input  y como  menciona  todedano  debo modifiar  mi widget  pero no se como  esa es la  ayuda que  estoy  solicitando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí te dejo lo que esperas como resultado, como comentabas que se descuadraba, no se necesitaba eliminar esas lineas de código simplemente era necesario cambiarlas de linea:

El cambio que hice fue:

- Sacar el `label` del `div` con la clase `input-group` , basándome en tu primer código.

ó bien

- Agregar el `label` fuera del `div` con la clase `input-group` con base al segundo código.

Te dejo el resultado del segundo codigo:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="alumno" class="hidden-xs col-sm-2">Alumno:</label>
      <div class="input-group col-sm-10">
        {{form.persona_display}} {{form.persona_display.error}}
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-add"          type="button"><span class="glyphicon                     glyphicon-plus"></span>Alumno</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias JuanKGlezz, agradezco tu  ayuda. !!!!